# Ender 3 X-axis values are not correct

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, x-axis

So I just got the Ender 3 and have been trying to print out a part. However, I noticed the printer is trying to print the part, which should be centered in the bed, on the left side.

I performed the auto home, leveling procedures, prior to execution, but it still wants to print it on the left side.

I checked the values it thinks it has for X, but they are about 60 mm to high (i.e. from the control/move axis menu, I move it towards the zero position and when it touches the switch, it still thinks its around 65-70 mm in the positive direction).

I have tried the good old power cycle, but each time it seems to get worse printing closer and closer to the edge. I am sure that I must have fudged something up. Anyone know how to fix the mismatched position?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! I've moved the question from Meta to the main site for you.

Comment: Sorry the question is not quite clear to me. With `but it time it` you mean `but in time it`? Are you implying that there is layer shifting? I.e. the layer on top of the older layer does fit over it exactly, but prints shifted from the old layer?

Comment: Can you show a photo of the problem? If you order the printer to home, it should set the switch position to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issues with the digital display values, was caused by the X-axis binding up and not advancing. I had to move the axis via the control panel in the positive direction and noticed once it got about half-way out, it wouldn't advance for like two or more steps.

On the control panel, it said I was 235 mm out from the home position, but in reality I was more around the midway point. When I would move it back to the home position the read-out still displayed that I was offset from the home position in the positive direction.

To fix it I tore it down and reconstructed it (made sure everything was plumb and level), I also flipped the belt in the opposite direction (teeth down, so that the stepper pulley grips the belt teeth).

Comment: Your comment `flipped the belt` implies that you'd actually assembled it wrong. If the belt teeth don't engage with the pulley cog then it's likely to slip which could cause the problem you observed since the motor would turn, but the belt may or may not move!